# Parsing preferred phonenumbers with CNPhoneNumber from vcf-file

Tags: ios, objective-c, vcf-vcard, cncontact

I try to parse a vcf-file. I use CNContact for this. That works quite well, but with the phonenumbers i have a problem.

With `CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber*>*` I get the label (e. g. "home") and the phonenumber in the value.

Excerpt from the vCard:

`TEL;TYPE=home:1234567890`

But if the number is tagged with a "pref" i can't get this tag for the phonenumber.

Excerpt from the vCard:

`TEL;TYPE=home,pref:0987654321`

Is there anyway to find out, which numbers are the preferred numbers?

I use following code:

> ```
> for (CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber*>* number in cnContact.phoneNumbers) {
>  NSString *label = number.label;
>  NSString *number = ((CNPhoneNumber*)number).stringValue;
>
>   //Do some work with label and number
> }
> ```

Comment: There's no such concept as a "preferred" phone number with `CNContact`. Even using the Contacts app you will not see any way to make a phone number the preferred number. What it is that you are trying to do with the preferred number in the vCard file?

Comment: You can have multiple numbers, all with "work"-tag. One of them is the preferred number. If you add a Contact from vCard, which contains a preferred number, to the Contacts app you won't see it, but if you export it again, the tag "pref" is saved.